# Integrating Google or Bing map with Dynamics 365 for finance and operations

Tags: maps, microsoft-dynamics, x++

App: Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations
Product version: 10.0.18
Platform version: Update42

Requirement to update address of the record as per pointer in Google or Bing maps.

The MAP button in Addresses grid of "All customers" reads the address and open corresponding Bing map in new tab.

Q1: is there a way to show map in the form itself, maybe using X++ code?

Q2: The pointer or address in not movable, so how to do that and read and update the existing address?

Kindly help with understanding the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1:
Below is the post in Microsoft Forum that answers first question with the usage of HTML and JS resources in X++ form with observe method usage in order to get dynamics values

https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/437773/google-maps-in-microsoft-dynamics-365-finance-and-operation-s-form/1203259

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).